# How to exclude a directory and or subdirectory from inclusion using tar on CentOS 6.4

Tags: directory, gnu, tar, centos6

I have tried all the methods I can find on Google and even here on stackoverflow.  I know I can feed a file list to tar.  I'm wanting to use the tar command exclusively.

tar cvf fail.tar --exclude=/home/fun/pass1 --exclude=/home/fun/pass2 ../.

No matter what I attempt, using tagfile, using single, double quotes, various positioning on the command line, wildcard characters and the like, tar just seems to ignore the exclude parameter all together!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're using the absolute path to create the exclude.

```
$ touch f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 && ls<br> 
f1  f2  f3  f4  f5<br>
$ tar cvf fail.tar --exclude=./f2 --exclude=./f3 ./<br>
./<br>
./f1<br>
./f5<br>
./f4<br>
tar: ./fail.tar: file is the archive; not dumped
```